# Advice on writing a java method dealing with relational algebra

Tags: java, tuples, relation

So, I am working on a project for a Java course and have to write the following method:

```
// This method takes a comparison condition in the 5 parameters and
  // returns true if the tuple satisfies the condition and false otherwise.
  //
  // The comparison condition is coded in the 5 parameters as follows:
  //
  // lopType/ropType can take one of three values: "col", "num", "str"
  // indicating that the operand is either a name of a column, or a number,
  // or a string respectively.
  //
  // lopValue/ropValue will contain the name of the column if the lopType/ropType
  // is "col" and will contain a numeric value if lopType/ropType is "num" and
  // will contain a string value if lopType/ropType is "str".
  //
  // comparison will have one of six values: "<", "<=","=",">",">=", or "<>"
  //
  // As an example, if we want to express the comparison, SNAME = "Jones", the 5 parameters will be:
  // lopType="col", lopValue="SNAME", comparison="=", ropType="str", ropValue="Jones"
  //
  // As another example, if we want to express the condition GPA > 3.0, the 5 parameters will be:
  // lopType="col", lopValue="GPA", comparison=">", ropType="num", ropValue="3.0"
  //
  public boolean select(String lopType, String lopValue, String comparison,
  String ropType, String ropValue) {
  // Top level cases to consider:
  //
  // lopType="num" and ropType="num"
  // lopType="str" and ropType="str"
  // lopType="col" and ropType="num"
  // lopType="col" and ropType="str"
  // lopType="num" and ropType="col"
  // lopType="str" and ropType="col"
  // lopType="col" and ropType="col"

  }
```

I am pretty lost as to how to approach this task logically. I am trying to think about the pseudo code approaches to solving it. For reference, this Tuple has the following fields:

```
  private ArrayList<String> attributes;
  private ArrayList<String> domains;
  private ArrayList<Comparable> tuple;
```

where each element in the tuple has an attribute, domain and a value.
For example, one element may be A: "GPA", D: "INTEGER", V: "3.5", where A is the attribute, D is the domain and V is the value.

I have figured out conceptually that this method is going to "select" elements in the Tuple that satisfy the conditions that are passed in. There is a separate, Relation class that will use this method to return a Relation containing only the tuples that satisfy the provided method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am completely stumped.
Thanks!

Note: This is my first time posting on this site so I apologize if I overlooked any formatting norms for posting on here

Comment: What does the Relation class consist of?  What does the Tuple look like?  What effort have you made to create pseudo-code or write code?

Comment: Oof, that's a lot of stringly-typed data. If you're permitted, I would look at replacing the types and comparison parameters with enums.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Thanks for replying. One idea I had to begin this was to handle all the cases where the types being compared are the same first. For example if two integers are passed in. I also thought of creating a variable that could point to the comparator such as in integer -1 would be less than, 0 would be equal and 1 would be greater than etc. 

Tuple class: 
https://pastebin.com/APbPgUxr

Relation class: 
https://pastebin.com/63nG3M3v

Comment: @DavidConrad Unfortunately I can't change the parameters that are passed in for this project. Do you think it would be helpful to try and convert these params into enums?

Comment: If you can't change the parameters, I wouldn't worry about it.